# A riddle, as I get out of bed, What am I?

Tags: riddle, rhyme

What am I?

If you are me, you'll wait around more than the average bloke.

If you are me too much, too oft, it gets beyond a joke,

For few are me when they should be, when they'd like to be first,

And when they are my opposite, they all think themselves cursed.

All the fruit I ever eat is sadly green and firm.

I burn my tongue at every meal, but at least I have the worm.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answer:

> You are 'early'.

If you are me, you'll wait around more than the aveage bloke,

> Early arrivals must wait longer for the others

If you are me to much, to oft, it get's beyond a joke,

> Early party arrivals can be annoying?

For few are me when they should be, when they'd like to be first,

> You must be early to be first.

And when they are my opposite, they all think themselves cursed,

> Late folks are not happy being late.

All the fruit I ever eat is sadly green and firm,

> Unripe = not ready = too early

I burn my tongue at every meal, at least I have the worm.

> Eating too soon can burn you.  Early bird caught the worm.

Comment: I think the joke part might be referring to a...um...particular male inconvenience.

Comment: Mike M. - Yes, that seems very plausible.

Comment: +1 Well done.  The answer is correct, the explanations are good. 'Too much too oft' was really just a continuation of the previous line.